# Examples of rings where every left ideal is two-sided but not every right ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, examples-counterexamples, noncommutative-algebra

Is there an example of a ring where every left-ideal is two-sided but not every right ideal?

**WHAT FOLLOWS IS A FAILED EXAMPLE**

---

As an argument but not a proof that the example fails, consider:

$ f(a) \;a\; f(a) = 1 f(a) = f(a) $

Thus $f(a) (a \; f(a)) = f(a) \times 1$

This *suggests* that $(a \; f(a))$ must also be $1$ (it certainly can't equal $f(a)$ since $f(a)$ can't be idempotent), but I'm not sure how to make this an actual argument.

---

Let $F$ be the completely free algebra in the signature $(+, \times, f, \mathbb{Z}[w])$ where $+$ and $\times$ are binary functions, $f$ is a unary, and $\mathbb{Z}$ is a set of constants.

Additionally, let the function $d : F \to \mathbb{N}$ be defined as follows:

- $d(\mathbb{Z})$ is 0
- $d(f(x))$ is $1 + d(x)$ for all $x$.
- $d(x+y)$ is the maximum of $d(x)$ and $d(y)$ for all $x$ and $y$.
- $d(x\times y) = d(x+y)$

Next, I will build a set of equations, $\Delta$. The intent of this construction is to make $f(x)$ be a left inverse but not a right inverse of $x$ for every $x$.

- Let $\Sigma_0$ consist of the axioms of non-commutative rings, all variable-free true equations (i.e. of the form $t_1(\varnothing) = t_2(\varnothing)$) in $\mathbb{Z}$, and the variable-free equation $f(0) = 0$. Note that $\Delta_0$ is $f$-free except for a single sentence.
- Let $\Delta_0$ be the equational deductive closure of $\Sigma_0$. **Note** that $\Delta_0$ does *not* include the non-theorem $xy = yx$ because we can't conclude that it's true. We know that $xy = yx$ holds of all integers $\mathbb{Z}[w]$, but can't conclude that only integers exist.
- Let $\Sigma_1$ be the union of $\Delta_0$, sentences $f(x)x = 1$ for each $x$ such that $d(x) = 0$ and $x \neq 0$ is in $\Delta_0$, and sentences $f(x)x = 0$ for each $x$ such that $d(x) = 0$ and $x = 0$ is in $\Delta_0$.
- Let $\Delta_1$ be the equational deductive closure of $\Sigma_1$.
- Analogously, let $\Sigma_{n+1}$ be the union of $\Delta_n$, sentences $f(x)x = 1$ for each $x$ such that $d(x) = n$ and $x \neq 0$ is in $\Delta_n$, and sentences $f(x)x = 0$ for each $x$ such that $d(x) = n$ and $x = 0$ is in $\Delta_n$.
- Let $\Delta_{n+1}$ be the equational deductive closure of $\Sigma_{n+1}$.

I define $\Delta$ as $\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\Delta_n$.

I define $A$ as $F/\Delta$, which is well-defined since $F$ is a completely-free algebra and $\Delta$ is a set of equations.

I claim that $A$ has precisely two left ideals.

Let $I$ be a left ideal of $A$. Suppose $I$ is $\{0\}$, then $I$ is closed under left multiplication by arbitrary elements of $A$. Suppose $I$ is not $\{0\}$. It follows that $I$ has a nonzero element $c$. $f(c)$ is a left inverse of $c$ and thus left multiplication by $rf(c)$ will hit the arbitrarily chosen ring element $r$ since $f(c)c = 1$ and thus $(rf(c))c = r(f(c)c) = r1 = r$. Thus, if $I$ is not $(0)$, then it is $(1)$.

Every left ideal of $A$ is two-sided since $(0)$ and $(1)$ are both two-sided ideals.

Comment: How do you know that 2 does not have a right inverse?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez ... You are right. $a2 = a + a = 2a$, so the integers are in the center at least. Furthermore, though, I think this construction just gives you back the rational numbers. Interpreting $f(n)$ as $1/n$ or $0$ as appropriate in the leaves of an expression, and then interpreting an entire expression as a rational number, e.g. $f(2) - f(3)$ would be interpreted as $1/6$ ... allows you to produce an inverse as a rational number ... which can then be re-expressed using $f$ ...

Comment: Since this question hasn't received an answer yet, I am going to replace $\mathbb{Z}$ with $\mathbb{Z}[w]$ and attempt to fix it that way. If this attempt also fails, I'll call out the example as a failed attempt to solve the problem, but not make further attempts to salvage it.

Comment: Sorry to ask you a question rather than anything about your question, but this construction you've used seems to be the answer to something I've been wondering about. I'm not familiar with the terminology, so I might have misunderstood you, but it seems like this free $f$ in the signature is like adjoining a function to the ring, which the ring is closed under. Could you tell me what this is called, and where I could learn more about it?

Comment: @ZoeAllen This is indeed adjoining a function to a ring and using that to get back a new ring. I also have no idea what it's really called. I cobbled this together from stuff I've seen recently. My immediate inspiration for this was completely free algebras in universal algebra, the definition of the tensor product (which involves modding out by a huge number of equations), and the generators and relations notation from group theory. You should ask a question about it; I'm also curious what the real version of this construction is called.

Comment: I just asked the question here if you're interested: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4657276/1107685

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there an example of a ring where every left-ideal is two-sided but not every right ideal?

This is called being a left-not-right **duo ring**.

Consider the twisted polynomial ring $k[x;\sigma]/(x^2)$ where $k$ is a field and $\sigma$ is a ring endomorphism of $k$ such that $1<[k:\sigma(k)]$. This means it's like the normal polynomial ring except you have a rule to commute coefficients like this:

$x\lambda = \sigma(\lambda)x$

We want our ring $R$ to be that ring modulo the ideal $(x^2)$.

It's easy to see that $Rx=kx$ is the only nontrivial left ideal, and that it is a right ideal too.

Now consider two different $\sigma(k)$ basis elements of $k$, call them $b_1$ and $b_2$. It is not hard to show that $b_1xR\cap b_2xR=\{0\}$, and of course given that the only nontrivial left ideal is $Rx$, they cannot both be left ideals (because then they would be equal.)

Comment: [DaRT query](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=84l&L=84r)